# fail to set view landscape in storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am trying to develop a landscape app on iOS, at the first step I want to set the view to landscape so I can design the view much easily.

But after I chose the orientation->landscape nothing happened in storyboard, I checked some tutorial video, all their storyboard view change to landscape right after set it.

Anyone know what causes the failure of setting landscape?

My Xcode is quite weird for several problems, I tried to reinstalled it but problems still existed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you are using size classes in xcode 6. If so then change your size classes to Regular Compact in storyboard. Or else turn off size classes and Autolayout.

Click on file inspector(leftmost button in the tab) and check whether autolayout and size classes are turned on.

Comment: Yes it works!  But why apple does this, it complicated designing if we need both portrait and landscape app...

Comment: You can design for both portrait and landscape using size classes turned on. Its pretty simple with size classes. Just add the constraints properly.  Size classes are good and easy. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the size from default "inferred" to lets say "ipad air"

and then try switching between potrait and landscape from simulated matrix .

Comment: It changes in this way. But I am wondering what's the difference between  simulated matrix->size and compact-regular size from bottom bar?

Comment: by default , storyBoard is 600*600 i guess ,so its square anyway ,so u need to change the size to something else where height and width are different  to experience  landscape and portrait .
what ever you do with simulated matrix , has nothing to do with real time app presentation , its just for designing as you said 
Compact-regular size -  its related to size classes , it has impact on real time presentation

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off the AutoLayout